# Opposite and horizontal property for labels in Pie Series

Tags: amcharts

I was wondering if there is any way I can show labels Horizontally for PieSeries above Pie Graph, as by default it is shown below graph and vertically. I tried to find a way similar to  Opposite property of AxisRendererX as given in [OppositeProperty](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/axisrendererx/#opposite_property) explanation, But I failed to show my labels in a Horizontal way above graph! An image of Pie Series that needs to be updated is attached for your reference.[image: PieChart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amcharts uses the full area you provide for a chart. If you set the `width` of your chart to a small value, you have the result you showed. If you resize your chart like I did in the code pen below, the labels are shown horizontally.

To change the legend position you can use the `legend.position` attribute.

> Available options are: "left", "right", "top", "bottom" (default), and "absolute".

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/legend/#Positioning

In your case you can use the following code to move the legend to the top:

```
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.position = 'top';
```

I created a [code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqQzNQ) for your example.